# Save admin product attribute in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I am new to **Magento 2.1** and still working out most things about it.

I've created a custom module to add an attribute to admin add/edit product page. It's a very simple set up of a title and text area. I've managed to `setup:upgrade` & `setup:di:compile` the module with no issues. It's showing within the admin add/edit product page. What's it not doing is saving any value I enter into textarea and save. This is where my knowledge starts to fall short.

here is my code

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category" type="Fellowship\PorductPriceMeassage\Model\Category" />
</config>
```

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- file: app/code/Fellowship/CategoryAttribute/etc/module.xml -->

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Fellowship_PorductPriceMeassage" setup_version="1.0.2" >
        <sequence>
                <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            </sequence>
        </module>
</config>
```

**ui_component > product_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- file: app/code/Fellowship/PorductPriceMeassage/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml -->

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="product-details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price Message</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="price_meassage">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">15</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price Message</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I am not 100% sure, but I suspect that, it's the code used in di & module xml which is stopping the value from being saved.

I will be very grateful if anyone could point out that where I am going wrong.

Comment: Have you created Model?

Answer (score 0):

Why do not add these fields with the admin interface?  https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-product-attribute-magento-2.html

If you really want to do it with a script, you need to add these new fields in the databse with setup or upgrade class: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/setup-scripts-magento-2/

Comment: Hi Mathieu. Thank you for a quick response. I've looked at using admin attribute controller before but you can't embed additional fields within 'product-details' panel on add/edit product page.